# How to append list using multiple dictionaries in python 3

Tags: python, append

As part of my studies, I had to use the append function to add:

```
video_ad_1 = {"title": "Healthy Living", "company": "Health Promotion Board", "views": 15934}
video_ad_2 = {"title": "Get a ride, anytime anywhere", "company": "Uber", "views": 923834}
video_ad_3 = {"title": "Send money to your friends with GrabPay", "company": "Grab", "views": 23466}
video_ad_4 = {"title": "Ubereats now delivers nationwide", "company": "Uber", "views": 1337}
video_ad_5 = {"title": "Get cabs now with UberFlash", "company": "Uber", "views": 90234}
```

into this list:

```
video_ads_list =[]
```

the expected output should be:

```
[{'title': 'Healthy Living', 'company': 'Health Promotion Board','views': 15934},
 {'title': 'Get a ride, anytime anywhere', 'company': 'Uber', 'views': 923834},
 .
 .
 {'title': 'Get cabs now with UberFlash', 'company': 'Uber', 'views': 90234}]
```

The question states that I need to use the append function.

Comment: Show your own effort and code to solve the problem

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework assignment. While Stack Overflow doesn't have a problem with questions *about* your homework, we're not here to do the homework for you. You need to try to solve the problem yourself and ask us a specific question about your attempted solution, rather than just posing the assignment as your question. Also, while *we* don't mind offering some degree of help with your homework, your teacher might see it differently! You may want to check your school's policies to make sure that asking for help online isn't considered cheating.

Answer (score 0):

google is our best friend, man. according to https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists

list.append(elem) -- adds a single element to the end of the list.

```
video_ads_list.append(video_ad_1)
```

And in the link you can find many other useful methods for list. Try and play with them. That is the way you can learn stuff

Comment: Hi! I have tried that method previously. But it only allows me to append one dictionary at a time. I even tried :
video_ads_list.append([video_ad_1],[video_ad_2],[video_ad_3],[video_ad_4],[video_ad_5])
print(video_ads_list).
But it gave me back the error code :TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (5 given).

Answer (score 0):

You can use append function in a loop. A single line solution to this would be by using `extend`

```
video_ad_1 = {"title": "Healthy Living", "company": "Health Promotion Board", 
"views": 15934} 
video_ad_2 = {"title": "Get a ride, anytime anywhere", "company": "Uber", "views": 
923834} 
video_ad_3 = {"title": "Send money to your friends with GrabPay", "company": "Grab", 
"views": 23466} 
video_ad_4 = {"title": "Ubereats now delivers nationwide", "company": "Uber", 
"views": 1337} 
video_ad_5 = {"title": "Get cabs now with UberFlash", "company": "Uber", "views": 
90234}
video_ads_list =[]
video_ads_list.extend((video_ad_1, video_ad_2, video_ad_3, video_ad_4, video_ad_5))
```

Comment: That `extend` call is a silly way to add multiple values to the list. You have to *build* a tuple with the values in order to pass them all to the `extend` method. If you're doing that, you should just switch the parentheses for square brackets and make the list directly with a literal `[video_ad_1, ...]`. There's the same issue with your suggested loop (you can't loop over the variables without putting them in something iterable, but the most appropriate iterable to use is the list you're expecting as output). I suspect the questioner's teacher just expects a bunch of `append` calls in a row.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, I think Blckknght is right. I might just have to add a bunch of append calls in a row. I was just thinking if there were any more elegant ways to approach this question instead of writing a bunch of append calls. 
Thanks for the help! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list:

```
video_ads_list=[video_ad_1,video_ad_2,video_ad_3,video_ad_4,video_ad_5]
```

Or still the best:

```
video_ads_list=[globals()['video_ad_%d'%i] for i in range(1,6)]
```